# SQL - GROUP BY all possible variables

Tags: sql, teradata

I have been looking for a way to do this but I can't seem to find the solution.

How can I select and group by without removing all possible variables from column 2 where variable is non existent for variable from column1?

[image: Excel Example]

Data Example (left) - How I would like it to be (middle) - current (right)

When I would do this:

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, COUNT(*) 
FROM Table
GROUP BY Column1, Column2;
```

If I would use this line of code, I won't be able to see all the variables from column2 for each variable for column1 (which I would like to). Because if they don't exist it won't show in the results.

So I would like to see all the variables from Column1 with all 4 possible variables from Column2 and then the count for the amount this combination exists.

Thanks for the help in advance, hope my question is clear.

Comment: How many rows are in that table and how many distinct values exist for each column?

Comment: There are many rows in the table. Thought it doesn't really matter as it is just a multiple of the example.

Comment: Basicly more then 100.000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a `cross join` and then `left join` and aggregation:

```
select c1.column1, c2.column2, count(t.column1)
from (select distinct column1 from t) c1 cross join
     (select distinct column2 from t) c2 left join
     t
     on t.column1 = c1.column1 and t.column2 = c2.column2
group by c1.column1, c2.column2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of distict combinations and the number of rows in your table and per combination it might be more efficient to use your existing Select and extend it with a Cross Join returning all possible combinations (similar to Gordon's technique, but aggregating *before* then join):

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Sum(Cnt)
FROM
 (
   -- existing combinations
   SELECT Column1, Column2, Count(*) AS Cnt
   FROM mytable
   GROUP BY Column1, Column2

   UNION ALL

   -- all combinations
   SELECT c1.column1, c2.column2, 0 AS Cnt
   FROM (SELECT DISTINCT column1 FROM myTable) c1 CROSS JOIN
        (SELECT DISTINCT column2 FROM tmyTable) c2
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY 1,2
```